# Magento get product collection via custom observer

Tags: magento, product, observers

I have a custom observer in Magento 1.8.1.0 that is called on Product view page when current product having any upsell products. I have verified (using Mage::log()) that the observer is working, however when I try the following:

```
public function updateUpsells(Varien_Event_Observer $oObserver)
{
    $iCurrentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
    $oUpsellCollection = $oObserver->getCollection();
    foreach ($oUpsellCollection->getItems() as $key => $oUpsellProduct) {
        $aCategoriesIds = $oUpsellProduct->getCategoryIds();
        if (!in_array($iCurrentCategory, $aCategoriesIds)) {
            $oUpsellCollection->removeItemByKey($key);
        }
    }
}
```

On `echo $oUpsellCollection;` i got nothing returned ?

Is anyone know how to get upsell products collection ? Is this a proper way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$upsellCollection = $_product->getUpSellProductCollection();
```